# Why is Community♦ downvoting questions/answers?

Tags: support, voting, community-user

I realized that when looking  [Community♦](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community)'s profile there is:

> 606,827 Votes Cast
>
> all time
> 108,530 up
> 498,297 down

What is the voting algorithm of this bot? Upvoting old questions is understandable, but, *downvoting*? What are the criteria for downvoting? It looks like a downvoter machine to me.

Comment: The [community user owns down votes on deleted posts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19738/who-is-the-community-user/19739#19739)

Comment: And also those on migrated posts. No link handy though...

Comment: @ff524: not deleted posts, on *spam and offensive* posts. The goal being that it is clear that the post has no trust from the community before it gets deleted.

Comment: @Deduplicator: Aren't downvotes on migrated posts cleared? Or was it just a negative score..

Comment: @Deduplicator: ah, votes are reset [when the post has a negative scores](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31088/reset-post-score-to-0-on-migration). So downvotes on a post with a positive score presumably are owned by the CU.

Comment: @ff524: no. A vote on a deleted post is still yours. That way when the post is undeleted the vote counts again. Reassigning the votes to the CU would be pointless here, as CU votes count just as much in scoring.

Comment: Side question, [how do I have more **profile views** than Community?](http://i.imgur.com/WSc0dDR.png) That can't be right.  Has nobody looked at the community page... in six years?

Comment: It's mentioned in the about box: *I do things like - Own downvotes on spam/evil posts that get permanently deleted*.

Comment: @KyleMit I'm guessing that's how many profile views Community had received by the time its stats were (probably) paused/halted since Aug 26th 2008 - the date when it was allegedly last seen.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

When you flag a post as offensive or as spam, an automatic down-vote is cast. That down-vote is attributed to the Community User. See [What are the “spam” and “rude or abusive” (offensive) flags, and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58032/what-are-the-spam-and-offensive-flags-and-how-do-they-work/58035#58035).

> Each flag carries an implicit downvote for calculating the post's score *(it does not affect the caster's reputation)*.

If a post has one or more Very Low Quality flags on it a down-vote is cast when those flags are marked helpful, see [Do closed questions automatically get downvoted or not?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212871/do-closed-questions-automatically-get-downvoted-or-not/215328#215328)

> Although it's not particularly well-known, [Very Low Quality flags have carried with them an automatic downvote for about two years now](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93595/is-the-very-low-quality-flag-too-ambiguous/93606#93606). This extra downvote - attributed to Community - is cast *when the flag is marked helpful...*

In addition, when a post is migrated and it has a score of 0 or higher, all votes on the new post on the target site are owned by the Community User; both up and down. And last but not least, if a high-reputation account with a lot of voting history is deleted rather than cancel these votes those are transferred to Community User as well. Wether or not user votes are transferred is decided on a case-by-case basis and is rather rare.

The Community User account is the *system account*. The Stack Exchange database model makes sure that all votes are attributed to *someone*, even if that someone is the system account.

Comment: _When you flag a post as offensive or as spam, an automatic down-vote is cast_ I didn't know that, thanks

Comment: Probably a foolish question. But if spam/offensive flag got declined, will community retract the downvote?

Comment: @MartijnPieters seems like a loophole a sadist could exploit. How about flagging and downvoting than just a downvote? :-S

Comment: @Sufian: see how far that behaviour gets you before receiving moderator attention..

Comment: @FamousBlueRaincoat: right, yes, but that's not going to be the majority of the downvotes. :-)

Comment: @FamousBlueRaincoat: incorporated into the answer now.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: apparently the downvote *is* meant to be retracted: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160862/bug-in-automatic-downvote-for-closed-narq-and-off-topic-questions/161116#161116 If it doesn't any more, that's probably a bug.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy: ah, I was making an assumption, an assumption that is probably wrong. Good find!

Comment: @Krishnabhadra: the vote is retracted; Qantas found a [reference post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160862/bug-in-automatic-downvote-for-closed-narq-and-off-topic-questions/161116#161116) that shows this should happen when flags are declined.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ok, thanks for clarifying :)

Comment: Heh, the fact that the person applying a flag is a *caster* makes me think this is specific to the RPG Stack Exchange.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: wait, I thought I can use a downvote whenever I think it's not useful. Why shouldn't I flag as spam at the same time? Unuseful spam happens quite often. Why should that draw moderator attention?

Comment: @ᵺṓᵯᶏᵴ: not sure I follow you. Of course you flag spam as spam. You are free to add an extra downvote on top of the auto-downvote, but as you have a limited number of votes in a day, I'd just keep them for something else.

Comment: @MartijnPieters when a post gets to -6 it is hidden. so for less traveled sites, with moderators not on duty.  A spam flag and a down vote get the spam off the front page sooner.

Comment: @JamesJenkins: or, for less travelled sites, you want a little *more* attention to get it flagged as spam *faster*. In any case, [Tavern on the Meta](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta) is chuck full of spam hunters that would be happy to help flag such posts.

Comment: @MartijnPieters maybe you could add that as an answer at [How to attract the attention of cross site moderator?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214894/how-to-attract-the-attention-of-cross-site-moderator)

Comment: @bjb568: Thanks for the Very Low Quality heads-up. The downvote is cast when the flag is marked as helpful; *usually* the post is also deleted, but it is a technical nuance that is important, especially since pending VLQ flags are marked helpful when a question is closed. Added in a reference.

Comment: @JamesJenkins: this is at best comment worthy; feel free to do so there.